Ubuntu installation on Micromax Canvas P690 Tab
I am looking to install Ubuntu on my Micromax Canvas P690 Tablet as this is having Android v4.4.4 which is kind kind of outdated and none of major applications can be used. Hence I am trying to install Ubuntu on it to explore more compare to other operating systems. Can someone please help me.
